# Replacing characters in a string in C++

Tags: c++, c, database, string

In my application, I will be retrieving error message strings from a database. I would like to substitute numbers into the error message. The error message will be a C style string like:

```
Message %d does not exist
```

or

```
Error reading from bus %d
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to do a C style printf using this statement, and substituting my own numbers in. I know I can just do it manually, but is there an easier way to somehow use it like a string in a regular printf?

Comment: What's wrong with using `sprintf()` from libc?

Comment: @yan buffer overflows. Better to at least use `snprintf`

Comment: How can I use sprintf to do this?

Let's say I read the text into a variable char *text="Message %d does not exist"

I can use that to print that text to a buffer, but how can I substitute for %d?

Comment: @DavidBrown I didn't mean `sprintf()` specifically, I meant the `s*printf()` family of functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C++ way is to use std::stringstream:

```
std::stringstream str;
str << "Message " << messageName << " doesn't exist";

std::string out = str.str();
```

There is also very nice header-only boost [string algorithms library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/string_algo.html):

```
std::string message = "Message %s doesn't exist";
boost::replace_first( str, "%s", "MyMessage" );

// message == "Message MyMessage doesn't exist"
```

and [`boost::format`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/format/), which acts like printf, but is entirely type-safe and supports all user-defined types:

```
std::string out = format( "Message %1 doesn't exist" ) % "MyMessage";
```

Comment: boost::format is probably the closest thing to what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apart for simple string concatenation or using `<<` together with number and a message.

I can think of [`boost::format`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/format/)

```
int message_no=5;
std::cout << boost::format("Message %d doesn't exist") % message_no ;
```